# How to calculate formula field to other column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, formula

I have a SQL Server columns with data like this:

```
formula    amount  ficheno
-----------------------------
100*444    100     6555
10*698     698     6555
```

I've already tried on SQL Server converted `varchar` to double getting error.

Need to get formula field to resulted field...

Comment: Ideally don't store your data like this. The only way to get the result of the expression is to use dynamic SQL, and that opens you up to Injection; especially if you arent validating the values in your table.

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate an expression using dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = (
    select  string_agg(cast(
            'select ' + formula + ', ' + str(amount) + ', ' + str(ficheno)
            as nvarchar(max)), ';')
    from    YourTable
);
declare @temp table (id int, amount int, ficheno int);
insert @temp exec(@sql);
select * from @temp;

-->

id      amount  ficheno
44400   100     6555
6980    698     6555
```

[Working example at db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=90cfee3a6842150b171934746ed1389a)

Comment: Im getting this error : STRING_AGG aggregation result exceeded the limit of 8000 bytes. Use LOB types to avoid result truncation.

Comment: @semt20: Updated the answer to cast the argument to `string_agg` to `nvarchar(max)`, as suggested [here](https://itsalljustelectrons.blogspot.com/2018/03/STRINGAGG-Return-Types.html).  What result does that give?

Answer (score 0):

Ive followed your query and succeed Thank you so much @Andomar. Reviewed code to work on sql server<2017 with stuff function.  If anyone is looking for answer ;

```
  declare @sql nvarchar(max) = (

 SELECT  STUFF( (SELECT ' select ' + str([LOGICALREF])  + ', ' + str([LOGICALREFI])  + ', ' + REPLACE( Formül,',','.') +';'

               from BM_211_URETIM_PLANLANAN t

               for xml path ('')

              ), 1, 1, '' )

  )

    declare @temp table ( [LOGICALREF] int, [LOGICALREFI] int, [Planlanan Miktar] FLOAT);

    insert @temp exec(@sql);
```